# Applescript Keystroke "⌘+" gives an error

Tags: applescript, keystroke

My applescript isn't working. I want a keystroke that does `⌘+` on my mac.
Here is my current  code.

```
set abc to "+"
tell application "System Events"
keystroke command & abc
keystroke a
end tell
```

When I click play, I get the error

> "System Events got an error: Can’t make {command, \"n\"} into type text." number -1700 from {command, "n"} to text.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to press modifier keys is

```
set abc to "+"
tell application "System Events"
  keystroke abc using command down
end tell
```